# Can I use other language than english for names of documents and collections in firestore?

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Will using other language than english might produce any error later if not in development process?

[image]

Comment: May it causes problem while you assign **key** while fetching or uploading data to firebase.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits), you can use any UTF-8 characters for collection and document IDs.  I have even used emojis.  It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using Different Languages in **Collection** / **Document_Id** will be problematic in Sometime.

You can make things easier with Put Field `Language` and specify the language.

Which will help you to ORDER_BY.

```
Ref.orderBy("language").limit(3);
```